# Синоним слова филигранный

Tags: синонимы

Можно ли использовать слово талантливый, как синоним филигранный и на сколько это уместно?

Answer (score 1):

Синонимы к *филигранный* — искусный, тонкий. Вряд ли уместно заменять на *талантливый*, разве только в определенных контекстах, которые мне с ходу и не придумать.

Comment: Скажем, искусный - умело, хорошо. Мастерский выполненный.
Чтобы выполнить искусно, нужен не только навык, но и талант...

Comment: Мастерски выполненная вещь — талантливая вещь?

Answer (score 1):

Прецизионный, высокоточный.

Answer (score 1):

Синонимы к слову "филигранный" можно разделить на группы, у них **немого разная семантика**: 1) тонкий, тончайший, тщательный; 2) искусный, отточенный; 3) очень точный, учитывающий все детали.

Примеры

Порадовал филигранный  (точный)подбор актёров на главные роли.

У него несравненный филигранный  (отточенный, тщательный, проработанный в деталях) стиль.

Словно волны крови смыли ажурную тоску сумеречного быта, сломали его филигранный  (тонкий, изысканный) индивидуализм и открыли перед человечеством панораму титанических размахов и далей…

Этот фокус, требующий филигранного ( искусного, отточенного) мастерства, на зрителей почему-то сильного эффекта не производил.

Но в чем-то, с точки зрения профессиональной строгости, Галич был прав, и мне это было интересно для понимания его собственного творчества ― скрупулезно точного во всем, филигранного.

Answer (score 0):

Филигранная работа - тщательная, высокоточная, тонкая, требующая внимания и мастерства